# how do you make and populate a listView in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have spent too long to populate a listView in a fragment.

I don't want a list fragment or have it be populated by a DB, just want it populated manually also if you could show how to make it so that you can scroll that would be helpful.

The "rootView.findViewById" comes up with the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'rootView'"

here is my code:

public class Favourites extends Fragment {

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(fragment_favourites, container, false);

    String[] favouritefoods = {"Lasagne", "cheese Burrito", "jalepano bread", "chedder cheese"};

    //Build adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> favefoodadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(), //some context for the activity
            R.layout.favelist, //layout to be displayed(create)
            favouritefoods); //strings to be diplayed



    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.favefoodslist);
    listView.setAdapter(favefoodadapter);


    return rootView;
}
```

}

and fragments_favourites.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="activity.Favourites"
android:id="@+id/favefoodfragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/favourites_textview"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="45dp"
    android:text="favourites"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_below="@id/favourites_textview"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Edit fragment_home.xml to change the appearance"
    android:id="@+id/textView3" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/favefoodslist"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Please help and put it in plain simple English I am new to this. Thank you.

LOGCAT:

```
08-18 13:24:57.100  31954-31954/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.nrnazz747123.navigationapp, PID: 31954
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView
            at activity.Favourites.onCreateView(Favourites.java:40)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:953)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:456)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: are you new in coding too? If not, just declare a global variable: `View rootView` then set `rootView` in `onCreateView`.

Comment: I don't see any error with current code. Try clean an rebuild. What's on line 40 in Favourites ?

Answer (score 1):

In activity you cannot use `this` as your `context`. You need to get activity your fragment belongs to as your context with `getActivity()`.

Next, you cannot perform `findViewById()` operations before you actually have the view. The view is created in `onCreateView`, but you are calling it in `onCreate` already. Everything view related must be performed on view you get from `onCreateView`. To find your `ListView` you'll have to move it there and call it

```
ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.favefoodslist);
```

**EDIT**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(fragment_favourites, container, false);

    String[] favouritefoods = {"@@@", "!!!!", "...", "..."};

    //Build adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> favefoodadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(), //some context for the activity
            R.layout.favelist, //layout to be displayed(create)
            favouritefoods); //strings to be diplayed



    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.favefoodslist);
    listView.setAdapter(favefoodadapter);         


    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I have an error with the rootView. what you have told me works fine except that bit. I do not know how to initialize the rootView and it keeps asking for it. Again thanks for the fast answer and the help.

Comment: @helpplease look at your `@Override public View onCreateView` . rootview is there.

Comment: i see it is there but it says it cannot resolve the error.

Comment: Edit your question with how the code looks now + exact wording of the error.

Comment: @helpplease See my edit. Ditch the `populateListView()` method and move the logic into `onCreate` .

Comment: no errors however the app crashes when the fragment is opened

Comment: Again, edit your question with your CURRENT code + xml

Comment: I saw. And I commented the error logcat shows is not present there. Try clean, rebuild.

Comment: You error `android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView` means that id `favefoodslist` in your xml belongs to `RelativeLayout` and not `ListView`. In xml that you edited it doesnt look like it therefore your error must be in files you havent shown.

Comment: THANK YOU POSS; your code was perfect but it was the R.id.favelist. the textView was in a Linear Layout. Thank you again for helping out quickly and consistently.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using static data, you should do it in onCreateView method. If you need to repopulate it when you load data, for example, you should initialize the adapter with an empty ArrayList. When you got the data, copy it to the empty ArrayList and call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged().